# How to change path of an existing Windows Explorer window?

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-shell

I have the handle of an opened Windows Explorer window.

How can I send a command to it in order to change the path from 
*example: m:\programs to d:\programs*.

[image: example]

Till now I was using `ShellExecute()` but it opens a new window. This is not good (user experience).

Comment: You have an HWND to explorer? Aren't you means to use IShellBrowser and IShellView for this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I'll google some info for your recommendation. Thanks.

Comment: @Kabamaru: No need to Google, since you know you are heading towards MSDN: [`IShellBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775123(v=vs.85).aspx), [`IShellView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774834(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand , DavidHeffernan, can you please provide an example?

Comment: Why is honouring the user's configuration on whether to reuse windows not a good UX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following `BrowseToFolder` function navigates the existing instance of a Windows Explorer of the given `AHandle` handle (if exists) to a `AFolderPath` folder (if exists). If you won't specify the second parameter, the topmost window should be taken to navigate (or at least the documentation claims that; reality seems to take the oldest existing window). The function returns True, if the navigation has been successful, False otherwise:

```
uses
  ActiveX, ShlObj, ShellAPI, SHDocVw;

const
  IID_IServiceProvider: TGUID = '{6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA}';
  SID_STopLevelBrowser: TGUID = '{4C96BE40-915C-11CF-99D3-00AA004AE837}';

function GetItemIDListFromPath(const AFolderPath: WideString): PItemIDList;
var
  Count: ULONG;
  Attributes: ULONG;
  ShellFolder: IShellFolder;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if Succeeded(SHGetDesktopFolder(ShellFolder)) then
  begin
    Count := 0;
    if Failed(ShellFolder.ParseDisplayName(0, nil, PWideChar(AFolderPath),
      Count, Result, Attributes))
    then
      Result := nil;
  end;
end;

function BrowseToFolder(const AFolderPath: WideString;
  AHandle: HWND = HWND_TOPMOST): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
  WndIface: IDispatch;
  ItemIDList: PItemIDList;
  ShellBrowser: IShellBrowser;
  ShellWindows: IShellWindows;
  WebBrowserApp: IWebBrowserApp;
  ServiceProvider: IServiceProvider;
begin
  Result := False;

  if Succeeded(CoCreateInstance(CLASS_ShellWindows, nil, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
    IID_IShellWindows, ShellWindows)) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to ShellWindows.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if (AHandle <> HWND_TOPMOST) then
        WndIface := ShellWindows.Item(VarAsType(I, VT_I4))
      else
        WndIface := ShellWindows.Item(VarAsType(SWC_EXPLORER, VT_UI4));

      if Succeeded(WndIface.QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowserApp,
        WebBrowserApp)) then
      begin
        if (AHandle = HWND_TOPMOST) or (WebBrowserApp.HWnd = AHandle) then
        begin
          if Succeeded(WebBrowserApp.QueryInterface(IID_IServiceProvider,
            ServiceProvider)) then
          begin
            if Succeeded(ServiceProvider.QueryService(SID_STopLevelBrowser,
              IID_IShellBrowser, ShellBrowser)) then
            begin
              ItemIDList := GetItemIDListFromPath(AFolderPath);
              Result := Succeeded(ShellBrowser.BrowseObject(ItemIDList,
                SBSP_SAMEBROWSER or SBSP_ABSOLUTE));
            end;
          end;
          Break;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Here is the example usage:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ExplorerHandle: HWND;
begin
  ExplorerHandle := 123456;

  if not BrowseToFolder('c:\Windows\System32\', ExplorerHandle) then
    ShowMessage('Navigation to a folder failed!')
  else
    ShowMessage('Navigation to a folder succeeded!');
end;
```

Here is a [`complete testing project`](https://code.google.com/p/projects-stackoverflow-tlama/downloads/detail?name=11359795.ZIP) and [`the blog post`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/20/188696.aspx) from which I've taken the inspiration.

Comment: Glad I could help (with a big delay though :-)