# change current path in windows explorer

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

The question may seem like it already has an answer in this forum, but this case is some what different.

I am creating an application that will launch when a particular file is double clicked in the windows explorer and show a dialog window. This window will take some input and do some operations. Everything upto this is ok and running successfully.

Now when the operation is done, I want this application to change the path that was open in the explorer window.

I have seen an answer that might be helpful in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15182556/2003263), but I do not understand it as it is in delphi.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I can get the current path from the file itself, and open a new explorer window. But if an explorer window is open (the one showing the file), how to change its path?

Comment: The linked question may be Delphi, but all the intelligence is in the WinAPI COM functions called. It's in fact a lot easier to call those from C++.

Comment: Just call `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems()`. Does it really matter if the user ends up with two explorer windows open instead of one?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the link in the stack overflow answer you will find another link to a blog where you can find nearly all code in C++. [Here the link again](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/20/188696.aspx).

Comment: That link is dead

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20171025065411/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040720-00/?p=38393